# Object-oriented fractal tree

Tags: javascript, performance, object-oriented, ecmascript-6, fractals

I made an object oriented fractal tree in javascript using the p5 library, it consists of three files:

- Fraternal Tree.js
- branch.js
- flower.js

[Here](https://github.com/MasterYushi/Fractal-Tree-Object-Oriented-/tree/4b59da30f282b2a177cdfd3cdda4c6da72315cc4) is the github repo with the source code. All the main work is done in **Fraternal Tree.js**
I want to know if I am following good coding practices and naming conventions or not. Also, if you increase the number of branches to anything above 1000, the fps drops significantly, is there a way I can optimize this to get better fps? Maybe using more efficient data structures? Or some other practice?

**You can run the sketch [HERE](https://masteryushi.github.io/Fractal-Tree-Object-Oriented-/)**

Code :

## Fraternal Tree.js -

```
var tree = []; //stores branch objects including the root
var flowers = []; //stores flower objects

//flower objects are assigned only to ungrown branches on clicking "grow" button
//this array is cleared on clicking "shed" button

var branchNumber = 0; //stores number of branches(excluding root)

//used for buttons and checkboxes    
var shrink, shake, intensity, grow = false,
    shed, gravity, flsize, grav, wind_dir, windcheck;
var cnv;

function setup() {
    cnv = createCanvas(500, 500);
    //create a root at the bottom middle of the screen
    var root = new Branch(createVector(width / 2, height), createVector(width / 2, height - 100));
    tree[0] = root;
    //code in between to setup dom elements
    cnv.mousePressed(branchIt); //create branch on mouse press

function draw() {
    //this is the animation segment, gets called fps times every second
    background(51);
    fill(255);
    textSize(24);
    text("Number of branches = " + branchNumber, 15, 30);

    //determine value of wind vector based on dom elements
    if (windcheck.checked()) {
        if (wind_dir.value() == "Left")
            wind = createVector(-0.2, 0);
        else if (wind_dir.value() == "Right")
            wind = createVector(0.2, 0);
    }

    //loop through branch objects
    for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
        tree[i].show(); //display every branch object
        if (tree[i].flower) //if flower for current branch exists, set its value
            tree[i].flower.size = flsize.value();
        //shake function shakes the tree
        if (shake.checked()) {
            tree[i].shake(intensity.value());
        }
        if (!tree[i].grown && grow && tree[i].flower) {
            tree[i].growFlower();
        }
        //apply forces if shed button is pressed and flower exists 
        if (shed && tree[i].flower) {
            if (grav.checked()) {
                tree[i].flower.applyForce(gravity);
            }
            if (windcheck.checked())
                tree[i].flower.applyForce(wind);
            if (!tree[i].flower.done)
                tree[i].flower.shed();
        }
    }
}
function branchIt() {

    for (var i = tree.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!tree[i].grown) {
            tree.push(tree[i].spawnA(shrink.value()));
            tree.push(tree[i].spawnB(shrink.value()));
            branchNumber += 2;
        }
        tree[i].grown = true;
    }
}
```

#### Some less important code :

`shedFlowers` is called when shed button is pressed.
`growFlowers` is called when grow button is pressed.

```
function shedFlowers() {
    if (grow)
        shed = true;
    flowers.splice(0, flowers.length);
}
function growFlowers() {
    grow = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
        if (!tree[i].grown) {
            var flower = new Flower(tree[i]);
            flowers.push(flower);
            tree[i].setFlower(flower);
        }
    }
    shed = false;
}
```

## branch.js -

```
class Branch() {

    constructor(start, end){
      this.start = start;
      this.end = end;
      this.grown = false;
      this.flower = null; //every branch has a null flower
    }    
    shake(intensity) {

        this.end.x = constrain(this.end.x + random(-intensity, intensity), this.end.x - 2, this.end.x + 2);
        this.end.y = constrain(this.end.y + random(-intensity, intensity), this.end.y - 2, this.end.y + 2);
    }

    setFlower(flower) {
        this.flower = flower;
    }

    show() {

        stroke(255);
        line(this.start.x, this.start.y, this.end.x, this.end.y);
    }
    spawnA(size) {

        var dir = p5.Vector.sub(this.end, this.start);
        dir.mult(size);
        dir.rotate(PI / 4);

        var newEnd = p5.Vector.add(dir, this.end);
        var right = new Branch(this.end, newEnd);
        return right;
    }
    spawnB(size) {

        var dir = p5.Vector.sub(this.end, this.start);
        dir.mult(size);
        dir.rotate(-PI / 4);

        var newEnd = p5.Vector.add(dir, this.end);
        var left = new Branch(this.end, newEnd);
        return left;
    }

    growFlower() {

        this.flower.draw();
        this.flower.update();
    }    
}
```

## flower.js -

```
class Flower() {


    constructor(branch) {      
      this.size = 10;
      this.velocity = createVector(0, 0);
      this.acceleration = createVector(0, 0);
      this.pos = branch.end.copy();
      this.done = false;
      this.lifespan = 255;
    }

    draw() {
        //get colour from colour picker            
        var colour = document.getElementById("colour").jscolor.rgb;
        fill(colour[0],colour[1],colour[2], this.lifespan);
        // fill(document.getElementById("colour").jscolor.toHEXString(),,,this.lifespan);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.size, this.size);
    }
    update() {
        if (!this.done)
            this.pos = branch.end.copy();

        this.pos.add(this.velocity);
        this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);

        this.acceleration.mult(0);
        if (this.done) //only start fading after shed button is pressed
            this.lifespan-=0.8;
    }
    shed() {
        this.applyForce(createVector(random(-1, 1), random(-1, -0.1)));
        this.update();
        this.draw();
        this.done = true;
    }
    applyForce(force) {
        this.acceleration.add(force);
    }
}
```

## Update #1

I replaced all the functions in **branch.js** and **flower.js** with prototype functions, this helped but the results were no where near significant. And some ES6 sugar syntax.

Comment: Would SVG not be a good alternative since it doesn't require re-drawing the tree each time?

Comment: Of course it would be, but that's not what the point, I want to improve this, not  completely replace it with something else/better.

Comment: does it need to be object oriented is functional programming style solution acceptable?

Comment: @user93 I guess it could be, in another language, however it needs to be in javascript, which is object oriented. Moreover, I don't have any experience with functional programming style

Comment: @MasterYushi  you can write functional code in javascript. Libraries like ramdaJs help you do that  http://ramdajs.com/

Comment: @user93 Still that would change the code and the approach completely, i am looking for enhancements, not replacements.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty easy to read and understand. However here are some minor suggestions for improvement:

The top level fields could be named in a way that does not require the almost trivial comments. If it is important to note that the array `flowers` stores flower *objects*, just call it `flowerObjects`. The `tree` is a bit misleading because one could assume that it is a tree object. The array could be named `allBranches` or even just `branches`.

I break up functions in smaller parts wherever possible. A good indicator are comments before a block of some coherent lines of code like in this example:

```
//determine value of wind vector based on dom elements
if (windcheck.checked()) {
    if (wind_dir.value() == "Left")
        wind = createVector(-0.2, 0);
    else if (wind_dir.value() == "Right")
        wind = createVector(0.2, 0);
}
```

This could be rewritten like this:

```
wind = getWindVector(windcheck.checked(), wind_dir.value());

function getWindVector(windChecked, dir) {
    let x = windChecked ? 0.2 : 0;
    if (dir == "Left") x = x * -1; 
    return createVector(x, 0);
}
```

Note that again the comment is made redundant.

Another indication that some pieces of code ought to be extracted to separate functions is that you are directly accessing the UI elements in the code that builds the tree. Note how hiding the `wind_dir.value()` behind the `dir` parameter made the code a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Good work updating to ES6 syntax. With ES6 come block scoped variables - declared with `const` and `let`. It is advised to default to using `const` and then switch to `let` when re-assignment is deemed necessary. This helps avoid [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085).

If you want to optimize this to get better fps you could explore ways to reduce calculations - e.g. consider [looping in reverse if acceptable](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-optimize-your-javascript-apps-using-loops-d5eade9ba89f/#optimizations).